# How would you refer to investment money with no strings attached?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word/term to describe some money that is disposed towards funding an idea but with absolutely no strings attached; meaning that, even if they guy just spends it all and gives nothing back in return, it's ok.

I know there are things like "angel funding" and "seed money" but they imply different things and are usually bound by a contract and some terms.

In spanish we refer to these investments as "fondo perdido", which would more or less translate to "lost funds".

Comment: A “grant” is a sum of money that is not returned.

Comment: “Non-repayable funds/loans ”  can be used in your example.

Comment: A good starting point for researching equivalent terminology is Google Translate. Search for the original phrase, then translate the page. In this case, I'm typically seeing "unrefundable". "Un crédito a fondo perdido" = "An unrefundable credit", for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think that money transferred with no strings attached would be classed as a **'donation'**.

One of the meanings listed by [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/56742?redirectedFrom=donation#eid) concerns the legal view of donations which is :

> Donation : 2. Law. The action or contract by which a person transfers the ownership of a thing from himself to another, as a free gift.

This is one way of not paying tax on one's estate - **donate** it to relatives during life (within seven years of death, I believe, it is free of all taxation).